# tar: "Cannot stat" when given arguments as shell variables

Tags: linux, tar

I have some directories in a location, that location's absolute path is stored in `PROJECT_HOME`. Now, I am trying to do the following in a script:

```
TARGET_LIST="bin lib scripts deployment"
tar -czf project.tar.gz -C "$PROJECT_HOME" "$TARGET_LIST"
```

but tar gives me the following:

```
tar: bin lib scripts deployment: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

The tar command works if I substitute the values of `TARGET_LIST` (`tar -czf project.tar.gz -C "$PROJECT_HOME" lib bin scripts deployment`), but doesn't when I use the variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting `$TARGET_LIST` between quotes you are defining a single argument with spaces. tar is looking for a single file/folder named 'bin lib scripts deployment'.

Try with

```
tar -czf project.tar.gz -C $PROJECT_HOME $TARGET_LIST
```

without the quotes

**EDIT**
If you have spaces in your file or directory names you need to use [arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) (as suggested by Ignacio)

Example

```
TARGET_LIST=(bin lib scripts deployment "a directory with spaces")
tar -czf project.tar.gz -C $PROJECT_HOME "${TARGET_LIST[@]}"
```

Comment: @Saadat: Only until you hit something with whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You're having the opposite of the problem described in [BASH FAQ entry #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Fortunately the fix is the same: use an array.